# Gitlab Webhook expresiones regulares conectado con jenkins

Tags: gitlab, jenkins, devops

[image: Gitlab]

Buen día, tengo la siguiente inquietud es posible que en las configuración de gitlab webhook con expresiones regulares o desde el mismo jenkinsfile se ejecute el job si el commit que hago tiene la palabra calve ej CI/CD y si no contiene esa palabra clave no me ejecute el job y si se puede también validar el correo, estoy integrando esto con jenkins

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: el correo deberia etar en `user_email` el tema de commits es que en un push puede haber muchos. lo mas simple sería un branch build; o del lado del que recibe el hook parsear el payload y hacer un fetch/pull seguido de build o ignorar

Comment: @aloMalbarez entonces para validar el correo es colocar el user_email en las expresiones regulares no debo hacer alguna configuración en el jenkins o el jenkinsfile